# passing a user input variable to another file

Tags: c#, xamarin

Im needing assistance on how to take a user input from a login page, check the Database for the username, and if it exist in the DB, pass it to another file that will pull the information pertaining to that username from the cosmosDB.

Below is the loginPage code

```
         using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace ToDoItems.Core.Pages
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
    {
        public LoginPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        async void SignInProcedure(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            User user = new User(Entry_Username.Text, Entry_Password.Text);
            if (user.CheckInformation())
            {
                //await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new CosmosDBService(Entry_Username.Text));
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new ToDoItemsPage());  
            }
            else
            {
                DisplayAlert("Login", "Login Failed", "Okay");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And Im trying to, first check the cosmosDB for the user name, then pass the username if it exist to the cosmosDBservice file to get the information associated with the username:

```
    using System.Collections.Generic;
               using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    
    using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;
    using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client;
    using System;

using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using ToDoItems.Core.Pages;

namespace ToDoItems.Core
{
    public class CosmosDBService
    {
       static string queryname;

        public CosmosDBService(string logname)
        {
            // store the parameter for use later;
            queryname = logname;
 
        }

        static DocumentClient docClient = null;

        static readonly string databaseName = "Tasks";
        static readonly string collectionName = "Items";

        static async Task<bool> Initialize()
        {
            if (docClient != null)
                return true;

            try
            {
                docClient = new DocumentClient(new Uri(APIKeys.CosmosEndpointUrl), APIKeys.CosmosAuthKey);

                // Create the database - this can also be done through the portal
                await docClient.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(new Database { Id = databaseName });

                // Create the collection - make sure to specify the RUs - has pricing implications
                // This can also be done through the portal

                await docClient.CreateDocumentCollectionIfNotExistsAsync(
                    UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri(databaseName),
                    new DocumentCollection { Id = collectionName },
                    new RequestOptions { OfferThroughput = 400 }
                );

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);

                docClient = null;

                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        // <GetToDoItems>        
        /// <summary> 
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        /// 


        public async static Task<List<ToDoItem>> GetToDoItems()
        {
            
            var todos = new List<ToDoItem>();

            if (!await Initialize())
                return todos;

            var todoQuery = docClient.CreateDocumentQuery<ToDoItem>(
                UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseName, collectionName),
                new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = -1, EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true })
                .Where(name => name.Name == queryname)
                .AsDocumentQuery();

            while (todoQuery.HasMoreResults)
            {
                var queryResults = await todoQuery.ExecuteNextAsync<ToDoItem>();

                todos.AddRange(queryResults);
            }

            return todos;
        }
        // </GetToDoItems>
```

Comment: you are already passing Entry_Username.Text to CosmosDBService on the constructor.  Is there a problem with doing it that way?

Comment: Just updated the code, but i guess my real question is how to receive the usename in the CosmosDBService file to be used in the todoQuery

Answer (score 0):

you are already passing the username to the constructor of `CosmosDBService`

```
public void CosmosDBService(string user) 
{
  ...
}
```

you need to create a class variable to store it

```
string username; 

public void CosmosDBService(string user) 
{
  // store the parameter for use later
  username = user;
  ...
}
```

then in your query use that class variable

```
public async static Task<List<ToDoItem>> GetToDoItems()
{
  ...
  
  .Where(name => name.Name == username)
          
  ...
}
```

Comment: you say im already passing it, but in my LoginPage file the code says "there is a constructor in CosmosDBService that excepts a argument, even after i have added the last 2 blocks of code you showed me up. Does that mean it a problem with the LoginPage passing or ComsosDBService receiving ?

Comment: I have no idea what you're actually doing.  Please post the relevant code

Comment: uploaded whole thing!